# create dns delegation where new nameserver are to be in the delegation on windows 2008 os

Tags: domain-name-system, delegation

We have a domain "muzzard.com" which has nameservers ns0 and ns1

I'd like to add a delegation aws.muzzard.com and have the nameservers for that delegation in there e.g. ns0.aws.muzzard.com  etc.

When I go through the new delegation wizard it asks for the FQDN's of the nameservers for the delegation.... which don't exist!

This must be possible..  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

The nameservers for the delegated zone must already exist and must also be authoritative for that zone before you can delegate to them.

Comment: so its not possible to have a nameserver ns0.aws.muzzard.com for a delegated zone aws.muzzard.com, where the nameservers are in the delegation.  its a bit chicken and egg.  right?

Comment: You mean for the Windows server? Because otherwise, NO, it is not necessary.

Comment: @bendecko Sure it's possible. I just described how it's done: set up the server, create the zone on the server, then delegate.

Comment: @bortzmeyer It may not be required, but it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The setup you describe is perfectly legal and quite correct. It works in many places. As a typical example, all the namservers of .NET are in a subdomain of .NET.

However, I do not know "the new delegation wizard" and cannot help about it.

Answer (score 0):

Like bortzmeyer, I am unfamiliar with the specific requirements of the MS DNS Server's provisioning wizards. It may be that you cannot do it with the wizards, however it **IS** a legal DNS delegation.

The situation you are describing is a common pattern in DNS administration and there is a name for the records which need to be inserted in the parent zone to assist the delegation.  They are called "glue records" and it may just be that you need to put glue records in the parent zone before you can proceed, or there may be some other MS-specific pattern for accomplishing this.

In any case I would recommend you familiarize yourself with glue records and perhaps search your documentation for the term "glue record", as I cannot believe you are the first to encounter this situation using Microsoft's DNS server.